# Vue.js - Repeated event handlers and memory use

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In a Vue.js template, if I want to attach a click handler to all table cells of a table with 100 cells, internally does that actually create 100 event listeners or is it clever enough to just create 1 event listener and know which element the click applied to?

Comment: Submitting as a comment and not an answer because it might be outdated, but I doubt it: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/is-event-delegation-necessary/3701/3

Comment: You can see what listeners are attached in the dev tools. If you select an element in Chrome the listeners are listed in the **Event Listeners** section, after **Styles** and **Computed**. Delegated listeners are also listed but it tells you which element the listener is on.

Comment: @skirtle - Yep, I can see it in there that there is an event listener created for every cell. Thanks, never knew about that section of the dev tools.

Comment: @RwwL - That appears to still be what happens, thanks for the link.